# Kubernetes Ingress Skaffold Documentation

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, skaffold

I am trying to add ingress to my Kubernetes documentation. I was able to add the ingress.yaml file, and there is plenty of documentation on ingress.yaml, but I am using a skaffold.yaml to handle the nitty-gritty of the Kubernetes deployment. And I cannot find any documentation on creating a skaffold file for ingress. ( that simply uses googleCloudBuild, buildpacks, and minikube ) all the documentation I come across is for NGINX.

My project looks like the following:

```
kubernetes-manifests:
--- frontend_service.deployment.yaml
--- frontend_service.service.yaml 
--- ingress.yaml
--- login_service.deployment.yaml
--- login_service.service.yaml
--- recipes_service.deployment.yaml
--- recipes_service.service.yaml
```

and my current skaffold file is the following:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta4
kind: Config
build:
  tagPolicy:
    sha256: {}
  # defines where to find the code at build time and where to push the resulting image
  artifacts:
  - image: frontend-service
    context: src/frontend
  - image: login-service
    context: src/login
  - image: recipes-service
    context: src/recipes
# defines the Kubernetes manifests to deploy on each run
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
    - ./kubernetes-manifests/*.service.yaml
    - ./kubernetes-manifests/*.deployment.yaml
profiles:
# use the cloudbuild profile to build images using Google Cloud Build
- name: cloudbuild
  build:
    googleCloudBuild: {}
- name: buildpacks
  build:
    artifacts:
    - image: frontend-service
      context: src/frontend
      buildpack:
        builder: "gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:v1"
    - image: login-service
      context: src/login
      buildpack:
        builder: "gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:v1"
    - image: recipes-service
      context: src/recipes
      buildpack:
        builder: "gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:v1"
```

This current skaffold file does not deploy in an ingress architecture, it uses a backend and a frontend tier.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more into why is cloud build tagged?

Comment: I am new to skaffold - and did not know if the build type changes configuration ( I am using google cloud build in this config ) But I will untag it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ingress definitions are just Kubernetes Resources, so you just add your `ingress.yaml` into the manifests to be deployed:

```
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
    - ./kubernetes-manifests/ingress.yaml
    - ./kubernetes-manifests/*.service.yaml
    - ./kubernetes-manifests/*.deployment.yaml
```